# Struct and arrays(C++) How to assign roll no to names using one array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I want to assign three roll numbers to three names but using only one array.. Please tell me how can i do that in c++. I think it is done using struct and arrays

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: I am student of software engineering in college and i don't know much about arrays... i know simple and multidimensional arrays but i don't know how to show roll nums to students using one array...i can do it by using two arrays..

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by roll numbers.  Show some examples of what you're trying to map, and then show an example of how you would do it using two arrays.

Comment: Please put clarifications/sample output in the question instead of in comments.

Comment: what i mean by roll numbers are just numbers like 10,23,50 etc.. i want output like: 
Adam  John  David
50       30      20

now i want this using only one array..
if I'd do this by two arrays then i'd define two array, one of char[3][10] and one of int[3]... char array will have names and int array will have numbers of those names..

Comment: by using two arrays I'd do like this::
int main(){
char names[3][10];
int numbers[3];
names={adam,david,john};
numbers={10,20,30};
cout << names << endl;
cout << numbers << endl;
return 0;
}

Comment: @AnonyDeveloper You should probably read a basic C/C++ programming book/tutorial first. Product types are simple elements of programming that should be covered in the very first chapters.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of std::pair. Prefer std::vector over raw arrays in c++, also highly prefer std::string over just an array of char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> //std::pair
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Raw array approach
    pair<string, int> nameNumbersArr[3];
    nameNumbersArr[0] = make_pair("Adam", 50);
    nameNumbersArr[1] = make_pair("John", 30);
    nameNumbersArr[2] = make_pair("David", 20);

    //Vector approach
    vector<pair<string, int>> nameNumbersVec;
    nameNumbersVec.push_back(make_pair("Adam", 50));
    nameNumbersVec.push_back(make_pair("John", 30));
    nameNumbersVec.push_back(make_pair("David", 20));

    return 0;
}
```

You can access the different parts of a pair using .first or .second

Example:

```
cout << nameNumbersVec[2].first << ' ' << nameNumbersVec[2].second << endl;
```

will print

```
David 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to make a map.  In C++, `std::map` is a built-in, so something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<int, std::string> stdNames;
stdNames[10] = "Bob";
stdNames[23] = "John";
stdNames[50] = "Mary";
```

Now if you do not have access to built-ins, you can implement a mapping structure yourself. `std::map` is usually implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), though you can use an [avl-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or any other kind of self-balancing binary tree for the same purpose.

Now it sounds like you're fairly early in your degree, so you may not be comfortable implementing these yourself.  In that case, you may want to create a `Record` struct, and have an array of those.

e.g. ([typdefs/structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c))

```
#define MAX_LEN 100
typedef struct {int rollNumber; 
                char name[MAX_LEN];} Record;
Record studentRecords[3];
```

Note that in this approach is really C not C++, and requires care around name lengths.  [Julian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38333801/4966481) shows you a C++ approach for this kind of result.

It really does sound like you need to read a couple of books from here though: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That `char` array in a C++ question really hurts.

Comment: From the OPs comments I figured they were really using C, but then they used `cout`... I could remove it, will wait to see what they add from the comments into their question.